Error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1 - AudioPlayers package
I am new to Flutter and am trying to build a simple xylophone app. Everything runs just fine, untill I install the AudioPlayers package to play some notes.
The print command for testing works, but as soon as I include the AudioPlayers I run into this error:
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':path_provider_android:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.


Could not resolve all files for configuration ':path_provider_android:androidJdkImage'.
Failed to transform core-for-system-modules.jar to match attributes {artifactType=_internal_android_jdk_image, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
> Execution failed for JdkImageTransform: C:\Users\stefa\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platforms\android-34\core-for-system-modules.jar.
> Error while executing process C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jbr\bin\jlink.exe with arguments {--module-path C:\Users\stefa.gradle\caches\transforms-3\4a46fc89ed5f9adfe3afebf74eb8bfeb\transformed\output\temp\jmod --add-modules java.base --output C:\Users\stefa.gradle\caches\transforms-3\4a46fc89ed5f9adfe3afebf74eb8bfeb\transformed\output\jdkImage --disable-plugin system-modules}


Try:


Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
Run with --scan to get full insights.
Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.

BUILD FAILED in 6s
Error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
Some additional information:

audioplayers: ^6.1.0 is added to pubspec.yaml
Flutter Doctor has all green marks, no issues
SDK version: 3.5.4
Android Studio Ladybug 2024.2.1 Patch 3

I have looked though similar questions online, but none solved my problem. I also looked on gradle.com but that did not help me, too complicated for me at the moment.
Also tried other Flutter audio packages, but could get none of them to work. All failed to build.
My code:
import 'package:audioplayers/audioplayers.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
void main() {runApp(XylophoneApp());}
class XylophoneApp extends StatelessWidget {
  //const XylophoneApp({super.key});

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: SafeArea(
            child: Center(
              child: TextButton(
                  onPressed: (){
                    print('Beep!!');
                    final player = AudioPlayer();
                    player.play(AssetSource('note1.wav'));
              }, child: Text('Click me')),
            ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

Can someone please give me some pointers how to get this solved? Beginner level comment please!
Thanks!!

I testing on Android Studio Ladybug Patch 2 it's work fine.
r u sure pubspec.yaml import files like example
-assets/note.wav
latest: audioplayers: ^6.1.0

pubspec.yaml imports -assets/
that should include all .wav files in that folder, right?

I also tried with -assets/note1.wav but I keep getting the same error

First clear cache and restart if not fix this issue then reinstall java and flutter sdk and check cmd ''flutter doctor'' if not work again then copy source file and install
Old version better like patch 2 as compare to new version sometime new version unstable.

I tried all these things but still got the same error message. But now in addition to the old error message, I got a new message telling me that it could be the AGP version. So I changed the reference in settings/gradle to 8.2.1. And now the code is working! Thanks!
